# Objective-C stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString : only native function work

Tags: javascript, objective-c, function

I use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in my project and i don't understand why it don't work.

If I write :

```
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('ok')"];
```

or

```
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"prompt('input')"];
```

It's Ok, the box is displayed in the webView.

But if write (in js file), `testt = function testt() {alert('ok');}`, and i call it with :

```
[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testt()"];
```

The box is not displayed, without errors.

To check, i can open Safari in developpement mode, and type testt() in the deb debug input, the box is displayed in the webView.

stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString don't work with a personnal function.

Somebody can tell me my error ?

Thank's by advance.

Comment: I had an javascript error in the loader of my page... :( Now I have an error : webKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener..    Somebody know what's the problem please ?

Comment: I cleaned my project, now i haven't any error, but stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString don't want to execute a personnal JS function. May be, stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString can't access at this function !? I added  viewDidStartLoad ,viewDidFinishLoad, didFailLoadWithError  to see if there was another error, but all is ok.